# shinydashboard increase size of dashboard page

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am using shinydashboard and my ui code is in this format:

```
ui = dashboardPage(skin="black", 
                   dashboardHeader(disable = T),
                   dashboardSidebar(width=300),
                   dashboardBody()

)
```

In one of the pages of my body the plots are larger than the page background and it looks like this:

[image]

Notice that the black background does not cover the plots on the page.

Is there argument to either dashboardPage() or dashboardBody() that controls height? Alternatively anyone know the correct html to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I once had a similar issue. Please try the following:

```
dashboardBody(
  tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML('.wrapper {height: auto !important; position:relative; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden}')
  ))
)
```

Comment: this solution does not work for me using shinydashboard 0.7.2. Is it outdated? You don't happen to have any ideas? 
Maybe the position of the tags call within the dashboardBody() is important? For useShinyjs() that seemed to be the case.

Comment: I'm using this solution with shinydashboard 0.7.2. and it is working fine. I'd put the head-tag in the body first, than everything else.